# Migrating a JavaScript\Ionic\Angular 1 App to Typescript\Ionic 2\Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm working on migrating an App from JavaScript\Ionic\Angular1 to Typescript\Ionic2\Angular2 one file at a time. I've poured over dozens of how-to's and such about migrating from one to the other, done the Angular 2 quick start and tutorial, and seen how to go from .js to .ts as well as installed all of the npm packages I need. Assuming I have everything I need to start the migration process, I really need help actually starting. I have dozens of files to convert, and it would help me greatly to just get one file converted correctly with the old code commented out to use as a reference to convert the others.

Here is a sample file. If you could convert this for me, or walk me through converting it, I would be very appreciative.

```
angular.module('myApp.app', ['ionic'])
    .controller('myApp.app', function($rootScope, $scope, AService, BService, CService){
        $scope.setUserName = function (user){
            $scope.user = user;
        };
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
            $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function (e, nState) {
                BService.setOnline(true);
            })
        })
    })
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is not complete, but gives you an idea of the direction you should be heading. It is a modified version of the boilerplate code that is created for you whenever you use the `ionic-cli` to generate a new app.

You would define your services each in a separate file in a subfolder of your `app/` folder called `services`. For example, your `AService` would be defined in `app/services/a-service.ts`. You import app level services at the top of your `app.ts` file and then include them in an array as the second component to the `ionicBootstrap()` function at the very bottom of the file. You also have to inject them as private variables in the `constructor()` of your `MyApp` component.

There is no longer anything like a `$scope` or `$rootScope` where you can store app-wide variables. Instead, you would create a provider (e.g. `UserData`) that you would use to store data that needs to be persisted across pages or sessions.

I recommend reading through the [Ionic 2 Conference Application](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app), which has been developed as a sample app using the Ionic 2 framework by its developers. It shows you how to handle things like user login, and persisting data across the app.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ionicBootstrap, Platform, Nav } from "ionic-angular";
import { AService } from "./services/a-service";
import { BService } from "./services/b-service";
import { CService } from "./services/c-service";
import { UserData } from "./providers/user-data";
import { HomePage } from "./pages/home/home";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "build/app.html"
})
export class MyApp {
    // the root nav is a child of the root app component
    // @ViewChild(Nav) gets a reference to the app's root nav
    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

    rootPage: any = HomePage;
    pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any }>;

    constructor(
        private platform: Platform,
        private aSvc: AService,
        private bSvc: BService,
        private cSvc: CService,
        private userData: UserData
    ) {
        this.initializeApp();

        // array of pages in your navigation
        this.pages = [
            { title: "Home Page", component: HomePage }
        ];
    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
            // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
            bSvc.setOnline(true);
        });
    }

    openPage(page) {
        // Reset the content nav to have just this page
        // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
        this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
    }
}

// Pass the main app component as the first argument
// Pass any providers for your app in the second argument
// Set any config for your app as the third argument:
// http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/

ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [AService, BService, CService, UserData]);
```

Comment: Could you possibly show me what this same code would look like with UpgradeAdapter implemented? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not very good with Angular1, and haven't ever had to upgrade an app, but [this article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html) has a pretty thorough description of the process and also has great links to external content describing the concepts and terminology.